# Limiting memory usage of a .net application

Tags: .net

Is there someway to limit how much a .NET application will use in terms of memory?

Comment: Please include why you wish to do this.

Comment: to stop runaway .NET applications hogging all a servers memory

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to limit the amount of physical RAM a .Net process can acquire correct?

Comment: See if this answers your question - [Set Windows process (or user) memory limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit)

Comment: Jared, yes,  I want to make sure no .net app can runaway with a whole bunch of memory.

Comment: YAU, thats looking very promising, ie Job Objects...   which theres a wrapper at http://jobobjectwrapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: having said that, surely there might be a command line tool that launches processes as a job object where you can limit its resource usage

Comment: What about non-.Net apps running away with a whole bunch of memory? Applications that are expecting to get more memory, for good or bad, will behave unexpectedly if you arbitrarily limit them. Most applications won't gracefully handle out of memory errors, which could lead to all sorts of problems.

Comment: not too worried about non .net apps,  and I'm not worried if the apps crash and burn.  well I am worried, but thats the lesser of two evils :)

Comment: @Keith Nicholas: Are you hosting other applications on the service?  If not, it's pointless to set a limit; I can understand if you have multiple services, but you shouldn't set limits arbitrarily, you should measure, measure, measure and make the best determination from there.

Comment: there are a number of services/applications/processes.   The box is kind of used for a lot of little processing jobs of various sorts.   So there's a mish mash of things going on.

Comment: @casperOne: I understand his point.  I just hit this, a .NET app that didn't actually need more than a few tens of megabytes gobbled over 20gb and effectively froze two VMs.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Process Governer: http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/set-process-memory-limit-with-process-governor/. I wrote this tool to test memory leaks in my applications.