# Can I cap a process's RAM usage?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible to put an artificial limit on the amount of memory a .NET process can use? I'm looking to simulate low-memory situations for testing purposes.

Right now we use a virtual machine for this type of thing.  It works, but I'm curious to know if we can figure out a more convenient approach. One that could easily be automated would be ideal.

**Edit:** As Hans Passant points out, just limiting the amount of virtual memory available to the process won't replace the VM-based tests.  The tests are for performance, so I would need to get swapping instead of `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit ... I might even go so far as to consider this one a duplicate.

Comment: @Wug - They're certainly similar, and it's looking like the solution might be the same.  But it's two different problems with slightly different requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One that could easily be automated would be ideal.

You can use [Windows Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) to manage this from code.  Processes can be associated with a job, and [JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to restrict the working set size.

Alteratively, you can call [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the process directly, which will restrict the maximum allowable memory usage for that process.

Comment: Just discovered [Process.MaxWorkingSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.maxworkingset.aspx), which appears to be the .NET equivalent to `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`.

Comment: @SeanU Yes - that will call SetProcessingWorkingSetSize

Answer (score 2):

The windows Application Verifier tool can simulate low resource levels, like low memory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480483.aspx

A more programmatic solution using job objects (as @ReedCopsey also suggests) is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17831/How-to-Set-the-Maximum-Memory-a-Process-can-Use-at

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  One note to add for posterity: According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx), Application Verifier refuses to work with managed code.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now we use a virtual machine for this type of thing

Which probably means you limited the amount of *RAM*.  That's not much of a test, a Windows process can never run out of RAM.  You'll just slow down the process, the operating system will be swapping pages more frequently.

The real limitation is available *virtual memory address space*.  Which is a fixed number for a 32-bit process, 2 gigabytes.  Give or take a few non-standard options to increase that number.  An OutOfMemoryException tells you that the process doesn't have a hole left in VM big enough to fit the allocation.

You can limit the amount of VM space by simply allocating a bunch of 50 megabyte byte[] arrays and storing them in a static variable of type `List<byte[]>` at the beginning of Main().

Comment: Very good point. I suppose I need to edit the question now. . .