# can windows services be isolated like app_pools for web?

Tags: .net, windows-services

Is it possible to isolate multiple windows services running on windows server 2008?

sort of like app pools work on web/ IIS.
Such that when one service has a memory leak, it wont crash the rest.

the problem I am facing is that I have a server that hosts 2 window services. One is mine and requires very little resources. The other is part of another teams that causes all the servers they code runs on to crash. I was looking for a way to isolate them because today my service stopped running because the server ran out of memory...

Comment: Part of the point of the app pools is to separate the web application(s) into separate  process... a Windows Service is a separate process already?

Comment: @StevenV  yeah - OP question does not make sense...

Comment: @StevenV - I added notes explaining the root of the question...

Comment: The reason IIS processes can have memory leaks. The reason they don't get out of hand is the app pool recycling that can be configured. I'd try sandboxing the service somehow, maybe using something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit ?