# How I can limit the heap's size so when I allocate a lot it won't get the machine stuck?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory

I have to debug program that rapidly allocates memory sometimes (Not by design.) and when it happens my whole computer just stop responding because physical memory goes 100% (I have 4GB ram), then I have to press the restarting button everytime with no way to know why did it happen.

Is there a way to limit `new`'s or `malloc`'s heap's size? By limiting I mean that it will throw exception like C#'s `OutOfMemoryException`. NOTE: I can't just pick all the `new`s and `malloc`s and replace it with customized allocator, it's a lot of work there.

I tried setting Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Heap Reserve\Commit Size to `256MB` or `256000000` but nothing works.

Comment: If the program starts allocating memory and completely stop responding, it may be an infinite loop somewhere. If this is the case, why you don't try to debug it instead?

Comment: /HEAP (Set Heap Size) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh.aspx

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira You didn't understood, my whole computer stopping to respond. I can't pinpoint the line because I have to press the restart button to continue work.

Comment: @AlexFarber Tried it, it doesn't help somehow.

Comment: If you switch to Linux you could use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) thru the `ulimit` bash shell builtin. Yet another reason to try Linux!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Unfortuately I need to program on&to Windows. Off-topic: I tried Linux for half a year.

Comment: You probably could redefine `::operator new` in a system specific way ...

Comment: See also this queston: The AppVerifier answer may be good for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit

Comment: See answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit on ideas on limiting memory usage

Comment: @Ben Is this a duplicate?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky, not really, because he doesn't need to limit the memory usage of the app, he needs to diagnose the reason for it.

Comment: @Ben I need it too. The question is more about to set memory limit per user. Allow the user 90% so the system will always have 10%. (?)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky sorry didn't notice it was your question. Your problem is that the application is using loads of memory and it shouldn't be. You need to find out why it is behaving badly and stop it. If you do, you won't have the other problem any more.

Comment: @Ben Yeah mine is for debugging purpose. (I didn't saw the difference somehow)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use the Debug Heap hooks in the CRT.

You can hook malloc to breakpoint when you allocate a large block, using `_CrtSetAllocHook` and `_CrtDbgBreak`. Or if your problem is lots of small blocks, you can set a breakpoint on the 10,000th allocation (for example) using `_CrtSetBreakAlloc`.

- CRT Debug Heap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
- `_CrtSetAllocHook`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/820k4tb8(v=vs.100).aspx
- `_CrtDbgBreak`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4wx2tde(v=vs.100).aspx
- `_CrtSetBreakAlloc`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wth1ha5(v=vs.100).aspx