# java runtime process limit memory

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I have a code like this

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test{    
    public static void main(String ars[]){
        try{
            Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr=rt.exec("a.exe"); 
            BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
```

How to limit the memory used by the a.exe ( like stop the execution after say 100MB) ?

Comment: downvoters can explain please

Comment: You are asking how to manage an application outside of the JVM.  The simple answer is, you don't.  Is it possible?  Sure, by calling all kinds of scripts and other applications.  But that is far more complicated and difficult than managing that without the java code.  Better to write a system script to handle it.

Comment: From Java, you dont want to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit