# Can I somehow protect the whole Windows machine from stalling in case my 64-bit program consumes all memory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, quota

Suppose I run some code which I know may contain a lot of defects. Those may be memory leaks or just bugs causing very high memory consumption. So let's say that today 8 gigabytes RAM is usual amount and that code gets crazy and consumes 8 gigabytes, then another 8 gigabytes forcing excessive page file operations, then 8 more gigabytes until the whole system just stalls. I tried that - Windows gets mostly unresponsive and useless in such case, the best bet is just powering the machine down and up.

Is there any way to protect the system from such cases? Perhaps some programmatic limits of how much memory the process is allowed to use?

Comment: Limited trick: running a process at lower priority helps a little bit (the shell only runs at default priority).

Comment: [Job Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193596/868014)?

Comment: I'd suggest asking on superuser

Comment: Maybe this helps https://serverfault.com/q/133122/141697

Comment: It looks like it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/192876/57428

Comment: If you wish to confine damage of running unknown binary code, just run it in a virtualized environment.